# Array Index Out Of Bounds Exception in Android

Tags: android

Im trying to do next,

I have an array with n amount of data and when I click the button called "Next" the array move to the next element doing a loop every time i click the button.

But I have a button called "Previous" that for obvious reasons it does the opposite, the problem here is that when the element is in the start position and need to move to the last position i get the following error

[java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLvOQ.png)

This is my entire code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView mStudentEditText;
    private Button mNext;
    private Button mPrevious;

    private Student[] mStudents= new Student[]{
            new Student(111,"Carlos",100),
            new Student(222,"Ana",60),
            new Student(333,"Luis",95)
    };

    private  int mCurrentIndex = 0;
    private void updateStudent() {
        mStudentEditText.setText("Numero de control: " + mStudents[mCurrentIndex].getNoControl()+"\n"+
                "Nombre: " + mStudents[mCurrentIndex].getName()+"\n"+
                "Calificacion: " + mStudents[mCurrentIndex].getScore());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mStudentEditText = findViewById(R.id.student_textview);
        mNext = findViewById(R.id.next_button);
        mPrevious = findViewById(R.id.previous_button);
        updateStudent();
        mNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCurrentIndex=(mCurrentIndex+1)%(mStudents.length);
                updateStudent();
            }
        });

        mPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex - 1) % (mStudents.length);
                    updateStudent();
                }


        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of `mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex - 1) % (mStudents.length);`

This makes the `currentIndex = -1` when the previous button is clicked. Hence updateStudent accesses `-1` index. Therefore the following error has occurred.

To prevent this you could do like this

```
if(mCurrentIndex > 0)
    mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex - 1) % (mStudents.length);
else
    mCurrentIndex = 0;
```